# Android Wear emulator goes into Ambient Mode automatically

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

I've been absent for some times from WearOS development. Now I am back and I have one annoying issue with the latest emulator - it goes automatically in Ambient Mode after few seconds. Not just my app, but the OS itself.

I Checked into the settings, tried clicking on the top of the window, but no luck - is there a settings for this or I should file a bug?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the emulator to be charging.
2. Make sure `Settings - Developer options - Stay awake when charging` is enabled.(default)

PS: Click `Settings - System - About - Build number` quickly to enable Developer options.

[image]